# Byte * to MemoryStream Conversion

Tags: c++, .net, command-line-interface

I am new to .NET programming paradigm. I am facing a problem.

I have one CLI library written in .NET which is used by my MFC project.

I have a memory buffer allocated using malloc

BYTE * lData = (BYTE *) malloc(lLen);

I pass this buffer to CLI Library. In CLI i need to convert this to MemoryStream.

As of now first i required to convert lData to Array and then set this Array to MemoryStream.

The question is when i convert lData to Byte Array it will allocate same ammount of memory again.

Will it also allocate same amount of memory when setting this to memoryStream?

If yes then is there a way to avoid this three times memory allocation?

Comment: Take a look at UnmanagedMemoryStream.

Comment: Thanks @Spook After creating UnmanagedMemoryStream(lData); Can i free lData or it will be released when the object of this memory stream will destruct.

Comment: What does the documentetion of this class say? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us/?query=UnmanagedMemoryStream

Comment: @Spook From documentation and the given sample code it seems that this block will not be released by UnmanagedMemoryStream Class. User need to release this explicitly